# Selenium generique Search Of Frames

Tags: java, selenium, recursion

i am working on automatisation project using selenium and java. project should able to work on **any** application/site.
So my problem now , since each web page can contains **infinite** number of iframes i need to develop a fonction able to search and iterate into all the iframes until it find the element i am looking for. 
Exemple : i look for a button with id="xx" to click:

```
<iframe>
        <iframe>
<iframe>
        <iframe>
                <iframe>
        <iframe> 
<iframe>
<iframe>
        <iframe>
        <iframe>
        <iframe> <button id="xx" />
```

i tried a recursive approach but its hard for me really:

```
public static void searchFrame2(String buttonid) {
    List<WebElement> frames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    boolean continuSearch = true;
    if (!frames.isEmpty()) {
        for (WebElement elem : frames) {
            if (continuSearch) {
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                driver.switchTo().frame(elem);
                try {
                    driver.findElement(By.id(searchByValue)).click();
                    continuSearch = false;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    List<WebElement> childFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
                    if (childFrames.isEmpty()) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        for (WebElement element : childFrames) {
                            continuSearch = recursiveSearch(buttonid, element);
                            if (!continuSearch) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean recursiveSearch(String buttonid, WebElement currFrame) {
    boolean continuSearch = true;
    while (continuSearch) {
        try {
            driver.switchTo().frame(currFrame);
            driver.findElement(By.id(buttonid)).click();
            continuSearch = false;
        } catch (Exception e) {// elem not found
            List<WebElement> childFrames = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
            if (childFrames.isEmpty()) {
                driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
                return continuSearch;
            } else {
                for (WebElement element : childFrames) {
                    continuSearch = recursiveSearch(buttonid, element);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return continuSearch;
}
```

Please someone help me here , i been stuck on this since 3weeks , i couldnt figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have written something in C# for this. You can convert it to Java. The repository is at 
https://github.com/zer0gr4v/testautomation201-iframe_switch.

Basically, nested iframes resembles an n-ary tree.(https://youtu.be/V4i7mdv1SMY). Sample code below.

```
        if(parentIndex==0)@this.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();  
        var iFrameList = @this.GetFrameElements(parentIndex);

        foreach (var x in iFrameList)
        {
            @this.SwitchTo().Frame(x.Index);             
            var searchedElement = @this.FindElements(locatorStrategy).ToList();
            if (searchedElement.Any())                
                return searchedElement;                
            @this.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
        }

        //Element not found.. Check children
        foreach (var x in iFrameList)
        {               
            if (x.HasChildren)
            {
                @this.SwitchTo().Frame(x.Index);                    
                var searchedElement = @this.GetElementInIFrames(locatorStrategy, parentIndex + 1);
                if (searchedElement.Any())                    
                    return searchedElement;
                @this.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();
            }
        }
        return new List<IWebElement>();
```

Comment: PLEASE man i tried to change your fonction to java , it didnt quite work , or mb i am missing something,  can you please help me to change it to java.  i get " element not attached exception "